# Cannot connect to an Oracle local database - cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Tags: python, database, oracle

I am trying to connect to an Oracle **local** database in Python 3.6.8 64Bit, but can't quite figure out how to achieve it. The Oracle libraries are installed, the OS is Windows 10 PRO 64Bit and absolutely all tried examples do not work at all.

The last example I tried:

```
userName = 'user'
password = 'pass'
with cx_Oracle.connect(userName, password, "localhost/orclpdb1",
        encoding="UTF-8") as connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("insert into SomeTable values (:1, :2)",
        (1, "Some string"))
    connection.commit()
```

**error thrown:** cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

What can be done to solve it?

PS: not even the official example for connecting to a DB without the TNSNAMES.ORA on Oracle's website works ("Easy Connect Syntax for Connection Strings").

Comment: Did you start the listener, `lsnrctl`, on server machine? See [How to Start, Stop, and Check the Status of the Oracle Database Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97665_01/html/rpm_81_installation_12c/GUID-21D99D16-AAB3-4AF0-A942-26C78D73AB89.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your Oracle Listener running?

```
cmd -> services.msc -> Oracle Listener (restart)
```

Is the Oracle Listener listening on port 1521 (default) ?

```
netstat -ab | findstr "LISTEN"
```

Is Database service "orclpdb1" exposed (in the list)?

```
cmd -> lsnrctl status
```

Make sure you can connect using sqlplus before you go on with python.

```
# when this works, you can continue with python
sqlplus user/pass@localhost/orclpdb1
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Will try to check it tomorrow - done for the day :-)

Comment: No Listener service is up on Windows! Thanks.